# How to stop Jupyter from generating regurlar HTTP requests

Tags: docker, https, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I used the official jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest image to setup a Jupyter Notebook, and enabled SSL by adding the following 2 lines in `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` (with certificate keys and certs copied to the right place).

```
c.NotebookApp.certfile = '/home/jovyan/.jupyter/server.crt'                                                     
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = '/home/jovyan/.jupyter/server.key'
```

I also did the following settings on the file:

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
```

After that, I'm getting the following SSL error on Jupyter server every 15 seconds:

```
[W 2022-11-26 08:37:44.071 ServerApp] SSL Error on 43 ('127.0.0.1', 33610): [SSL: HTTP_REQUEST] http request (_ssl.c:997)
```

It seems that some process within the docker container is sending an HTTP request to Jupyter server regularly.

My question:

1. What is the HTTP request being sent, and is there a way I can stop it?
2. If I cannot stop that http request, can I at least ask it to generate https instead of http?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To me, the error you show from the log, indicates that you're getting an incoming HTTP request on port 43 and your app, correctly, says that it won't do that.

Comment: Exactly, but how... I'm using a clean Jupyter data science docker image, so there should be no local requester pinging to that portal except myself. I'm not doing that btw...